# Вылетает ошибка при подключении к базе данных через фабрику DAO

Tags: java

Вот мой проект ([github](https://github.com/KuzmaJava/FLATSS)).

При подключении к БД через ConnectionFactory вылетает SQL Exception.

Не могу до конца понять в следствии чего это происходит?

```
public class ImplementFlatDAO implements FlatDAO {
    Connection conn;
    public ImplementFlatDAO(Connection conn) {
        this.conn = conn;
    }

    @Override
    public void init() {
        try {
            Statement st = conn.createStatement();
            try {
                st.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Clients");
                st.execute("CREATE TABLE Flats (id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, district VARCHAR(55), address varchar(95), square double, room int, price double)");
                System.out.println("The table has successfully created!");
            } finally {
                st.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
    }
}

public class ConnectionFactory {
    String url;
    String user;
    String password;

    public ConnectionFactory(String url, String user, String password) {
        this.url = url;
        this.user = user;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public Connection getConnection(){
        Connection conn = null;
        try{
            conn = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,password);
            System.out.println("Connection OK!");
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println("Connection Error");
        }
        return conn;
    }
}
```

Comment: Без сообщения об исключении непонятно.

Comment: Да и короткий кусок кода для воспроизведения ошибки тоже надо приводить, а не ссылку кидать

Comment: Текст ошибки в студию

Comment: @AlexanderChernin Просто выводит на консоль "Connection Error", я прикрепил кусок кода, где вылетает данная штука.

Comment: @ТатьянаСергеева  а какое сообщение находится в объекте ex.getMessage()? Выведите его вместо `ConnectionError`

Comment: @AlexanderChernin The server time zone value 'ÐÐ°Ð¼Ð¸Ð±Ð¸Ð¹ÑÐºÐ¾Ðµ Ð²ÑÐµ' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the serverTimezone configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.

Comment: Оно? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26515700/mysql-jdbc-driver-5-1-33-time-zone-issue

Comment: Вот еще, по-русски http://www.cyberforum.ru/java-database/thread1967034.html

Comment: @AlexanderChernin Да, вопрос решен, благодарю

Comment: @ТатьянаСергеева вот видите как важно читать сообщения из объектов ошибок (исключений) )

Comment: @AlexanderChernin Учту!

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE Flats (id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, district VARCHAR(55), address varchar(95), square double, int room, double price)
```

`int room, double price` изменить на `room int, price double`

Comment: Там еще int room. В SQL тип поля указывается после имени поля.

Comment: Изменила запрос для создания таблицы, но к сожалению ничего не изменилось, та же ошибка